# jQuery Shopping Cart

Tags: jquery, shopping-cart

i want to use shopping cart in my portal. can i get shopping cart plugin for jquery?

Gnaniyar Zubair

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this plugin http://plugins.jquery.com/project/add2cart

Answer (score 2):

http://simplecartjs.com/ not JQuery, but will do the job in case PayPal or Google Check out is ok for you.

Comment: simpleCart(js) is very nice. I recommend it.

Answer (score 0):

Well you have to browse the web on whether there exists such a plugin. But I guess you won't be successful. I doubt that you will find shopping card component that can be just placed on the portal and it will do it's job.

What jQuery may do is to help you in implementing it. You may use it for calling server-side webservices to store new articles that have been added/removed or give you visual effects as the one posted by pho3nix.

Answer (score 0):

How about ecwid (http://www.ecwid.com/) shopping cart?